# How to make TextBox style in XAML so that TextBox accepts only numbers

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to create Style for TextBox so that it only accepts numbers and no characters or special symbols.

Currently I am doing it with the help of back code (in C#) like:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
```

Is it possible to make XAML style for handling this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible with XAML only.  In my experience, the best thing to do is to derive from TextBox, add handlers to anything that could input text, and then validate the text as it comes in.  Either reject the change by handling the event, or accept it by letting the routed event propogate.

A general base class would look like:

```
public abstract class RestrictedTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected RestrictedTextBox()
    {
        PreviewTextInput += RestrictedTextBox_PreviewTextInput;
    }

    protected abstract bool IsValid(string proposed);

    private void RestrictedTextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        string proposed = GetProposedText(e.Text);

        if (!IsValid(proposed))
            e.Handled = true;
    }

    private string GetProposedText(string newText)
    {
        var text = this.Text;
        if (SelectionStart != -1)
            text.Remove(this.SelectionStart, this.SelectionLength);

        return text.Insert(this.CaretIndex, newText);
    }
}
```

To create a concrete instance for, let's say, a DoubleTextBox, you can easily do:

```
public class DoubleTextBox : RestrictedTextBox
{
    protected override bool IsValid(string proposed)
    {
        double throwAwayDouble;
        return double.TryParse(proposed, out throwAwayDouble);
    }
}
```

This will only allow you to input text that successfully parses to a double.  I'll leave it to you to handle the keydown-event (for spacebar) and the paste-event